# How to make Google marker url open in a new browser window or tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have some markers on a Google map and would like to make it open a new tab or window when they are clicked on. I only am able to open the clicked marker url in the same browser window tab.

This is how it works now...

```
var latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(MAP_FOCUS_LATITUDE, MAP_FOCUS_LONGITUDE);
var myOptions = {
   center : latlon,
   zoom : 14,
   mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
   mapTypeControl : false,
   navigationControlOptions : {
   style : google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.LARGE
   }
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapholder"), myOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
{
    position : new google.maps.LatLng(10.0,20.0),
    title : "Blah",
    url : "http://www.myurltest.com"
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
    window.location.href = this.url;
});
```

In HTML, normally you can do this to open a link in a new tab... so how do I get this effect ?

```
<a href="http://www.myurltest.com" target="_blank">Blah blah</a>
```

I would appreciate any assistance !

Comment: Check this for opening new tab with JS:

[Second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks. That is a good link too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The url property it's to define a sprite sheet for style the icon, nevertheless  change the callback of click for this

```
window.open(this.url, '_blank');
```

Comment: Hehe.. needs another 3 min to accept answer... will do it shortly